# Stripe paid trial period?

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription, trial

How can I set a subscription plan to a certain price? I want to offer trial periods, but I don't want them to be 100% free. I want to charge say, $1 so they feel they are making a financial commitment. Free sets a bad expectation. From what it looks like, I have only the option of free. How can this be changed?

Answer (score 11):

You'd still need to use a free trial period here but you'd just add a "setup fee" when you create the subscription. The easiest would be to create an invoice item just before:

https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem

Then create the subscription immediately after. It would automatically grab the pending invoice item and try to charge it.

Another method would be to use a one-off charge instead of the invoice item here.

Comment: Thank you,i will give it a try,have you any sample code for this as well

Comment: I could try, depends in which language you need it.

Comment: How about flat PHP ?

Comment: hi did you find a solution or source code?